# Can someone help me understand how XCode works?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been learning Python for about a year, but I thought I'd try my hand at iOS programming, so I bought a tutorial [book](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321699424). Unfortunately, the book uses an outdated version of XCode. Apparently, the ES1REnderer class files used in the book are no longer default classes. So, I checked Apple's developer website to see if they could help me, but they only have tutorials on XCode 4, and due to the fact that I don't have Lion, I'm using XCode 3.2.6. So my question is, should I just put all the code that would go in the ES1Renderer class files into the View Controller classes, or should I just find a new tutorial? I'm new to iOS coding, and Objective C in general, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "XCode" is [just] an IDE. It is not a language. It doesn't "work" any more than Microsoft Word "works". iOS is [family of] an operating system. Objective C is a language. Pick a focused goal: e.g. iDevice (iPhone, perhaps) development and get a book/tutorial for that. And yes, it is easiest to work with resources that target the version of the tools available -- this also includes the API used ;-)

Comment: You can have Xcode 4.2 without upgrading to Lion.

Comment: This isn't really a question about how Xcode functions, but how one of the older iOS source code templates was set up. That tutorial should not have been written against one of the stock templates, because those change with almost every version of Xcode that comes out. In any case, the book provides the source code for this project, so use that as a basis rather than starting from an Xcode template. Try to understand the overall concepts they're teaching first before becoming hung up on the specific steps in their implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Stick with the latest version of xcode and whenever you see a deprecated method from your book, look up apple's documentation to see what is the replacement.